# cURL - How to getting last redirect address

Tags: php, curl

i write some code in php.
I wanna get last redirecting adress on this is site:
fluege.de

I posting this is;

```
        $dep= "sFlightInput[accDep]=ZRH";
        $arr= "sFlightInput[accArr]=VIE";
        $depregion= "sFlightInput[accDepRegion]=";
        $arrregion= "sFlightInput[accArrRegion]=";
        $multidep= "sFlightInput[accMultiAirportDep]=ZRH";
        $multiarr= "sFlightInput[accMultiAirportArr]=ZRH";
        $ftype = "sFlightInput[flightType]=RT";
        $depcity = "sFlightInput[depCity]=Zürich+-+Flughafen+(ZRH)+-+Schweiz";
        $arrcity = "sFlightInput[arrCity]=Wien+-+Internationaler+Flughafen+(VIE)+-+Österreich";
        $sdate = "sFlightInput[departureDate]=29.03.2014";
        $srange = "sFlightInput[departureTimeRange]=2";
        $rdate ="sFlightInput[returnDate]=05.04.2014";
        $rrange = "sFlightInput[returnTimeRange]=2";
        $adt = "sFlightInput[paxAdt]=1";
        $chd ="sFlightInput[paxChd]=0";
        $inf = "sFlightInput[paxInf]=0";
        $cabin = "sFlightInput[cabinClass]=Y";
        $airline = "sFlightInput[depAirline]=";
        $send = $dep.$arr.$depregion.$arrregion.$multidep.$multiarr.$ftype.$depcity.$arrcity.$sdate.$srange.$rdate.$rrange.$adt.$chd.$inf.$cabin.$airline;
```

I using this ;

```
echo getLastEffectiveUrl("http://www.fluege.de/flight/wait/".$send);
```

And there is function

```
function getLastEffectiveUrl($url)
{
    // initialize cURL
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
    ));

    // execute the request
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    // fail if the request was not successful
    if ($result === false) {
        curl_close($curl);
        return null;
    }

    // extract the target url
    $redirectUrl = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $redirectUrl;
}
```

**They code must give this url;**
www.fluege.de/wait/?accDep=&accArr=&accDepRegion=&accArrRegion=&accMultiAirportDep=&accMultiAirportArr=&flightType=RT&depCity=Z%FCrich+-+Flughafen+%28ZRH%29+-+Schweiz&arrCity=Wien+-+Internationaler+Flughafen+%28VIE%29+-+%D6sterreich&departureDate=04.04.2014&departureTimeRange=2&returnDate=20.04.2014&returnTimeRange=2&paxAdt=1&paxChd=0&paxInf=0&cabinClass=Y&depAirline=

**But i need ;**

http://www.fluege.de/flight/encodes/sFlightInput/5f8ccad612bafb69e7693f04cfaf1458/ (etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided does not handle cookies, so if the site you are query'ing requires this, your code won't work.

I checked http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php, but it seems like cURL cannot store cookies in memory.  By adding the following line under `curl_setopt_array`, cookies are kept in a temporary file:

```
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'cookiejar'),
```

However, I did not get your specific case to work.  I noticed that the URL you create does not contain a question mark, and that the URL that your script creates does not redirect at all; it returns with `200 OK`. I checked this using the following shell command:

```
curl -LI 'http://www.fluege.de/flight/wait/sFlightInput\[accDep\]=ZRHsFlightInput\[accArr\]=VIEsFlightInput\[accDepRegion\]=sFlightInput\[accArrRegion\]=sFlightInput\[accMultiAirportDep\]=ZRHsFlightInput\[accMultiAirportArr\]=ZRHsFlightInput\[flightType\]=RTsFlightInput\[depCity\]=Zürich+-+Flughafen+(ZRH)+-+SchweizsFlightInput\[arrCity\]=Wien+-+Internationaler+Flughafen+(VIE)+-+ÖsterreichsFlightInput\[departureDate\]=29.03.2014sFlightInput\[departureTimeRange\]=2sFlightInput\[returnDate\]=05.04.2014sFlightInput\[returnTimeRange\]=2sFlightInput\[paxAdt\]=1sFlightInput\[paxChd\]=0sFlightInput\[paxInf\]=0sFlightInput\[cabinClass\]=YsFlightInput\[depAirline\]='
```

If it's unclear what the URL should look like, you should contact fluege.de to ask them how to use their API.

Comment: I already mentioned in my answer that, despite adding a cookie jar, you don't get your intended result. I changed my answer to elaborate on this. However, I'm afraid I can't help you further at this point, aside from giving you some pointers; the URL you create does not contain a question mark, it probably should. The URL you create does not redirect at all, so cURL gives you the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, curl can "store" cookies in memory like with COOKIEFILE etc

Comment: My interpretation is that COOKIEJAR and COOKIEFILE do the same thing, except that new cookies will not be stored in COOKIEFILE. In any case, the term "COOKIEFILE" suggests that the cookies will be stored in a file and not in memory.